# How can I resume a function after a promise fullfilment?

Tags: javascript, mysql, promise

I’m trying to set up a js messenger chatbot linked to a database.
Of course, sometimes, user requests data from the database to the chatbot and I do use promise to gather it. I recently learned about them, so I do only know the basics.
My issue is that when the promise is fulfilled, I not only need to trigger some code (which is done through the then() function) but also to return data to the main module in order to create an answer.
How can I resume my function (in order to reach the return) after the promise is fulfilled ?
I'm probably having a difficult time being understood so this is a sequence diagramm of my chatbot and some bits of my code.

[Main process of the database request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk1QW.png)

app.js

```js
const Database = require("./services/database");
const Message = require("./services/message");

app.get("/endpoint", (req,res)=>{
    let message
    //Check if the user message request data
    if (req == datarequest)
    {
        message = Database.request();
    }
    else
    {
        message = "You did not require any data";
    }

    Message.sendToUser(message);
});
```

DBInteractionModule.js

```js
async request()
{
    //Creating the promise
    let promise = new Promise(
        function(){
            let connection = db.connect();
            return connection.query("SELECT * FROM user;");
        }
    );

    // Only(?) way to use data when it returns
    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        console.log("data requested : "+ data);
    });

    //I need to use this return in order to give data back to the main app
    return promise;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: async function always returns a Promise(!). So you are returning Promise<Promise<...>>.
If you just return `data` (when success), the return value will be Promise with the data.
Then you can access your "data" in app.js using `then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are tricky the first time you use them, but once you get use to them, it's all about waiting then resolving or rejecting the promise.

I'm assuming, `db.connect` and `connection.query` both return a promise, so you have to wait for them to fulfill there promises.

```
 // the `async` word before the functions here is important
 const request = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // wait for the db to connect
    let connection = await db.connect();

    // wait for the db to return it's data
    const data = await connection.query("SELECT * FROM user;");

    // after waiting, if no error, the data should be available now
    console.log('Requested data (WITHIN the promise) : ', data);

    //return the data by resolving the main promise
    resolve(data)
});
```

Usage :

```
request.then(data => {
     console.log('Requested data (OUTSIDE the promise) : ', data);
     //Process data
});
```

Or inside another async function :

```
async function main() {
     const data = await request;
     console.log('Requested data (OUTSIDE the promise) : ', data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I understood this. However, the problem I'm facing here is that I cannot use async function (as I'm using existing code written to be sync only) and I need to reach the return function where my promise is. Like this : 
```
myFunction(){
const request = New Promise(...); //Creating my promise wich will get the db data

request.then({
// I could process data here but I want it to be returned to a parent function
});

return data;
}
```

Comment: I finally fixed my problem by putting async before every function I'm using in order to "await" everytime I call one.

But I still want to know if there was another workaround as (I think), the trick of making every function async probably don't work anytime.

I had to be such a nightmare back in the past when promise didn't exist and they had to use callbacks...

Comment: Glad this help you out and yeah it was a nightmare before ... now just remember, put `async` before any function that has a promise in it and `await` to wait for those promise to fulfill, always check the docs to see if any method return a promise, it can be anything form db call to image or video loading, Api, remote data ...